# pylibnet successfully installed,but returned "libnet.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: libnet

1, I installed libnet through "configure;make;make install", it returned success:

```html
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/home/fiontools/pcap/tool/libnet-1.2-rc3/win32'
make[1]: Entering directory `/data/home/fiontools/pcap/tool/libnet-1.2-rc3'
make[2]: Entering directory `/data/home/fiontools/pcap/tool/libnet-1.2-rc3'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c libnet-config '/usr/local/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/home/fiontools/pcap/tool/libnet-1.2-rc3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/home/fiontools/pcap/tool/libnet-1.2-rc3'
```

2, install pylibnet, returned success too.

```html
python setup.py install  
Searching for libnet...
/usr/local/include/
running install
running build
running build_ext
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/bin/lnsh to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pylibnet-3.0rc1-py2.6.egg-info
Writing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pylibnet-3.0rc1-py2.6.egg-info
```

3, when I use libnet, it returned no libnet.so:

```html
 python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libnet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libnet.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by adding lib path :

```html
$ export|grep -i ld_lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libnet
>>>
```